# javascript: How to access the Math objects type name

Tags: object, math, types

In one of our frameworks we show detailed type information about javascript objects during runtime... For most of ES6 objects that is very easy.
object.constructor.name mostly des the job.

But i totally fail with the Math object.

```
object = Math;
=> object.constructor.name: "Object"
=> object.toString() "[object Math]"  ok... but...
=> object.name: undefined             obviously
```

in Chrome Console I can see

```
Math { 
  abs: f, 
  ...;
  Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag),         = "Math"
  __proto__: Object
}
```

What to do with object to get "Math" as a result?

Comment: I guess i found it...
it is:
    object[Symbol.toStringTag]

This helped a lot....
https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-symbols/

but if I like this... I did not yet decide...

Comment: `class SomeClass {}`<br/>
<br/>
`SomeClass.name;`<br/>
`SomeClass.constuctor.name;`<br/>
`someInstance = new SomeClass()`<br/>
`someInstance.constructor.name;`<br/>
`    someInstance[Symbol.toStringTag];`      =>       undefined<br/>
`    SomeClass[Symbol.toStringTag];`          =>       undefined<br/>
<br/>
`    Math[Symbol.toStringTag]                     => "Math"`<br/>
<br/><br/>
I guess I do not like this chaos